# Mysql SET OPTIONS on version 5.6+

Tags: mysql, upgrade, deprecated

Ifter upgrading Mysql server from 5.5 to 5.7 we found that query 'SET OPTION' is deprecated. We asked our system's developers and they said that they are not plannig any updates to support newer mysql versions.
What can we do now? Is there any way to bypass this deprecated query?

I thinking we can set another server instance with version 5.7 replicating from old server 5.5.

Comment: You may consider downgrading your mysql until this issue is fixed. No point to upgrade a database to a version which is not supported by the application running on it.

Comment: We need to start using multi source replication feature included in mysql 5.7.